# Make elements of a canvas progressively fade out by successive clicks of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So, basically, I have created a canvas on which I draw points. The coordinates of those points are obtained via a JSON obtained from a url. Here's the function that draws the points:

```
function drawDATA() {
    getJSON('http://theossrv2.epfl.ch/aiida_assignment2/api/points/',
        function (err, data) {
        if (err !== null) {
            alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.circles.length; i++) {
                c.beginPath();
                c.arc(data.circles[i].x, data.circles[i].y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                c.strokeStyle = 'red';
                c.stroke();
                c.fillStyle = 'red';
                c.fill();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

where `c` is the context of my canvas.

Now, in the HTML code, I have a button that calls this function when it is pressed:

```
<input id="Refresh" type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="drawDATA();" />
```

As you can probably imagine, each time I press the button, new points are added to the canvas (while the points that were previously drawn stay). For example, once I open my HTML file and press the button twice, I have 6 points on my canvas (each time I click on the button, three points appear).

My problem is that I want the previous point to fade out in the following manner:

1. The first time I press the button, the first 3 points (call them A,B,C) appear normally.
2. The second time I press the button, three new points appear (D,E,F) and the opacity  of A,B,C is set to 75%
3. The third time I press the button, G,H,I appear, the opacity of A,B,C is set to 50% and the opacity of D,E,F is set to 75%

... and so on (so, after 5 clicks, the points A,B,C must completely disappear).

I tried to approach this problem by creating a CSS file that allows me to fadeOut some elements of my canvas, but it was far from the expected result (so I don't think it is necessary for me to show it).

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's unnecessary to show the way you tried to fade points on `canvas` using CSS because it's impossible. - Is there any JS code you tried?

Comment: No, not yet. Actually, what I'm trying to do now, is to store each point in a queue, then only draw the points in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to paint your whole canvas with an opaque layer **before** applying your new points:

```
c.beginPath();
c.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)';
c.fillRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);
c.closePath();

// draw new points here
```

**[Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/zohaqah/4/edit?html,css,js,output)**

---

#### Queue Array

If instead of painting the entire canvas with an opaque layer
you could create a queue array of sets of points that also have each a `alpha` property.

```
function drawSET( set ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < set.circles.length; i++) {
        var circle = set.circles[i];
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(circle.x, circle.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        c.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0,'+ set.alpha +')';
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0,'+ set.alpha +')';
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
    }
}

var queue = [];
var alphaStep = 0.2;

function drawDATA() {

    getJSON('http://theossrv2.epfl.ch/aiida_assignment2/api/points/', function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);

        queue.push( {alpha: 1, circles: data.circles} ); // Append
        if (queue.length > 1/alphaStep) queue.splice(0,1); // Remove first  
      c.clearRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height); // clear canvas

        for (var i=0; i<queue.length; i++) {
            var set = queue[i];
            drawSET( set ); // Draw as is
            set.alpha -= alphaStep; // And lower alpha for next iteration
        }

    });
}
```

**[Here's a live example - controlling each set opacity](http://jsbin.com/zohaqah/6/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this way seems to be more simple then creating a queue.

Comment: Oh, and btw, for those who are interested, to get the exact output that was required, it is necessary to draw the rectangle outside of the loop and set its opacity to 0.7 (that way we make sure that after 4 clicks, the first points disappear).

Answer (score 1):

## Re-render scene using alpha to fade.

You need to create an array holding the points. Each point has an alpha value that you decrease each time you draw it. When that alpha value reaches zero you remove the point from the array.

When you get new points you add them to the array of points setting their alpha to one and then render all the points.

Each time you draw the circles you must clear the canvas and draw all the circles. If you have other content on the canvas you must either redraw that content or save it as a separate canvas.

```
const points = [];  // array to hold points 

// clear canvas and redraw all points
function drawPoints(ctx, points){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i ++) {
        const point = points[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.globalAlpha = point.alpha;
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";       
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();

        // decrease alpha. Will fade through 0.75, 0.50, 0.25
        point.alpha -= 0.25;
        if (point.alpha <= 0) {  // remove point
            points.splice(i--,1);
        }
    }
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // restore the alpha 
}

function drawDATA() {
    getJSON('http://theossrv2.epfl.ch/aiida_assignment2/api/points/',
       function (err, data) {  // I am ignoring error
           // add new points to points array
           points.push(...data.circles.map(circle => {
              return {x : circle.x,  y : circle.y,  alpha : 1};
           }));
           // Use animation frame to ensure its presented correctly.
           requestAnimationFrame(()=> {
               drawPoints(c, points); // draw points
           });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could memorize the dots you drew in one iteration and redraw them with a color closer to the background color in the next iteration. You cannot retrieve previously drawn shapes in your canvas so it should be the best way to do it.

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

use a fillStyle of rgba.
Keep the alpha values in your data.circles array, then decrease them as desired, and use it

```
c.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,"+data.circles[i].alpha+")";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not get it.  If I do this, and then press the button, I will have 3 points, each with different opacity. But that's not what I want to do.

Comment: I thought that was exactly what you were after, I guess I don't understand the question then

Comment: Here's the thing. Press the button once, then 3 points appear (call them A,B,C). After that, press the button once again and 3 new points appear (call them D,E,F), and the points A,B,C (which you previously obtained) start fading away (meaning that the opacity of A,B,C is set to 75%).

Comment: so then my answer holds, the accepted answer seems to be doing what I suggested, not sure why you're downvoting

Comment: The accepted answer is an example of what I could do to achieve what I wanted (You're right, he was proposing smth that give me the same result as your answer). All I had to do (if you look at the accepted answer), is to draw the rectangle outside of the loop to get what I wanted. With your answer, it was not possible to do so. Btw, I am not the one that downvoted your answer